# How to fix htaccess RewriteRule back reference to RewriteCond? Fix for CPANEL AutoSSL Let’s Encrypt

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cpanel, lets-encrypt

CPANEL with AutoSSL (Let’s Encrypt) add automatic RewriteCond to htaccess because .well-known folder and keep updating htaccess file every X minutes, so you can't delete the "well-know" lines. But with this approach they break RewriteRule back reference to RewriteCond.

```
# www to non-www generic
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This example above don't work as spectated because %1 references last RewriteCond, and not the first where we filter the host with regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Some fix for generic www to non-www, using variables

```
# www to non-www (fixed to work with CPANEL - AutoSSL)
SetEnvIf Host "^www\.(.*)$" my_domain=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{ENV:my_domain}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

To bypass this problem use variable, it's not pretty but works!